# How to wait for API calls to finish and then return the result?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to make an api call several times :

```
const promises = recommendedMovies.map(({ id }) => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>  {
  tmdb.genre.movies(id, randomNumber, (err, response) => {
    if (!err) {
      resolve(response.results);                 
    } else {
      reject('error')
    }
  });
}));

const result = Promise.all(promises);
result.then(/*...*/).catch(/*...*/);
```

As you can see, I'm trying to wait for the API calls to finish and then return the result, which must be an array.

How can I achieve that?

```
const result = Promise.all(promises);
result.then(/*...*/).catch(/*...*/);
```

I'm getting the result first and then the API calls finish, so I get only an array of pending promises.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Promise.all(promises).then(results => { ... process each result });`

The **`Promise.all`** method
takes an array of promises,
and creates a new promise
that succeeds if all
promises succeed, and fails
if even one promise fails.
The succeed
callback receives an array of succeed values (`results` array above), one for each of the passed-in promises,
**in the same order**.

In your example you would process it like this:

```
const promises = recommendedMovies.map(({ id }) => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>  {
    tmdb.genre.movies(id, randomNumber, (err, response) => {
        if (!err) {
            resolve(response.results);
        } else {
            reject('error')
        }
    });
}));

const result = Promise.all(promises);
result.then( promisesResults => {
    /* promisesResults is an array where each element is result of promise at the same index */
    promisesResults.forEach( promiseResult => {
    /* .. process each promiseResult .. */
    };
}).catch(/*...*/);
```

For the reference there is also **`Promise.race`** which takes an array of promises and returns a completely new promise that resolves or rejects as soon as the first of the promises resolves or rejects. Succeed callback receives value of the first resolved promise.